# Issue with JFX TableView and HQL query

Tags: database, hibernate, javafx, tableview, hql

I have a small problem when trying to display data from my database in a JavaFX TableView.

I have a Student table

```
user_id  |   name    |    nick   |  password |  surname  | classroom_id
---------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|--------------
   2     |   AAA     | studentA  |  test123  |   AAA     |     1
   3     |   BBB     | studentB  |  test321  |   BBB     |     1
```

This table is connected to the Classroom table

```
  classroom_id | classrooName | classroomYear 
 --------------|--------------|-------------
       1       |  TestClass   |  2016/2017
```

I'm using this query to get all students together with the classrooms they belong to, no issue here. When I try to print out the values, everything is correct.

```
Select student from Student student Join Fetch student.classroom
```

Now, the actual issue is that the classroomName and classroomYear are not displayed in the TableView, like [this](https://imgur.com/a/tJfE2) (Jméno - Name, Příjmení - Surname, Nick - Nick, Třída - Classroom name, Rok- Classroom year)

The cell value factory for these 2 columns are

```
classroomNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("classroomName"));

classroomYearColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("classroomYear"));
```

Now, the only way I managed to get all the data to get displayed were to add classroomName and classroomYear to my Java classes which added them as 2 extra columns in the database. That kind of defeats the purpose of joining them with the id I think, is there any better way I can get the Classroom data displayed in my TableView?

EDIT: Here are Student and Classroom as Java classes

```
@Entity
public class Student extends User{

    private Classroom classroom;


    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(String name, String surname, String nick, String password, Classroom studentClassroom) {
        super(name, surname, nick, password);
        this.classroom = studentClassroom;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "classroom_id")
    public Classroom getClassroom() {
        return classroom;
    }

    public void setClassroom(Classroom classroom) {
        this.classroom = classroom;
    }

}


@Entity
public class Classroom {

    private SimpleStringProperty classroomName = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private SimpleStringProperty classroomYear = new SimpleStringProperty();

    private int classroom_id;

    public Classroom() {
    }

    public Classroom(String name, String year) {
        classroomName.set(name);
        classroomYear.set(year);
    }


    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String getClassroomName() {
        return classroomName.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty() {
        return classroomName;
    }

    public void setClassroomName(String name) {
        this.classroomName.set(name);
    }

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String getClassroomYear() {
        return classroomYear.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty classroomYearProperty() {
        return classroomYear;
    }

    public void setClassroomYear(String year) {
        this.classroomYear.set(year);
    }


    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name="id" , strategy="increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="id")
    public int getClassroom_id() {
        return classroom_id;
    }

    public void setClassroom_id(int classroom_id) {
        this.classroom_id = classroom_id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PropertyValueFactory` you use is looking for a property in `Student` called `classroomName`, which obviously doesn't exist. You need to implement the cell value factory yourself:

```
// assuming you declared
TableColumn<Student, String> classroomNameColumn ;

// ...

classroomNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
    Student student = cellData.getValue();
    Classroom classroom = student.getClassroom();
    if (classroom == null) return new SimpleStringProperty("");
    return classroom.nameProperty();
});
```

and similarly for the classroom year.

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm. I figured it's because there is no classroomYear and Name in the Student class but I had no idea how to write it. Thank you very much.